# How to create a Site to Site L2TP/IPSec VPN tunnel between two Synology NAS?

Tags: networking, vpn, nas, l2tp

My question is quite simple: I have two Synology NAS devices (running the latest version of DSM and VPN Server) installed at remote locations, each connected to a local LAN with an high-speed Fiber Internet access.

**What I would like to do is setup a site-to-site VPN tunnel between these two NAS, configured so that machines from LAN A can connect to machines LAN B and conversely.**

As far a I know, there are three solutions available using the VPN server package in DSM:

- **PPTP**: Excluded because of low security
- **OpenVPN**: I know how to achieve what I want using OpenVPN... but I believe it's a solution I cannot use since both NAS need to remain available as an OpenVPN server for other clients and AFAIK you cannot use OpenVPN both as a client and as a server on the same NAS (but if someone has a trick to overcome this limitation, it might be a solution :-D)
- **L2TP/IPSec**: Given the limitation above, that's the solution I am currently using...

Both NAS are configured as OpenVPN servers, then one NAS (in LAN A or "server LAN") is configured as a L2TP/IPSec server, and the other one (in LAN B or "client LAN") is configured as a L2TP/IPSec client and connects to the other NAS across the Internet. This works great, connection is very stable and so, and after having configured the routes properly on LAN A and B, machines from LAN B can successfully connect to machines on LAN A... however no matter what I have tried, I cannot make machines on LAN A talk to machines on LAN B!

To sum up:

```
Client LAN to server LAN --> OK
Server LAN to client LAN --> NOK
```

**Any ideas? :-)**

Notes:
I am open to solutions involving command line operations and manually editing configuration files on the NAS (for instance that's required with OpenVPN to set the reverse routes), but not involving third party VPN providers or additional hardware. ;-)

Comment: What *have* you tried so far? Is this L2TP/IPsec or plain L2TP?

Comment: It's LT2P/IPSec